# How to replace (or speed up) the parallel comparison when the number of pairs are extremely huge?

Tags: c++, data-structures

The run time of following code, parallel comparsion, takes forever, when the number of key in the map is huge(e.g 100000) and each of its second element have huge element(e.g 100000) as well.

Is there any possible way to speed up the the comparsion? My cpu is Xeon E5450 3.00G 4 Cores. Ram is fair enough.

```
// There is a map with long as its key and vector<long> as second element, 
//     the vector's elements are increasing sorted.
map<long, vector<long> > = aMap() ;
map<long, vector<long> >::iterator it1 = aMap.begin() ;
map<long, vector<long> >::iterator it2; 

// the code need compare each key's second elements 
for( ; it1 != aMap.end(); it1++ ) {
  it2 = it1; 
  it2++;

  // Parallel comparsion: THE MOST TIME CONSUMING PART
  for( ; it2 != aMap.end(); it2++ ) {
    unsigned long i = 0, j = 0, _union = 0, _inter = 0 ;

    while( i < it1->second.size() && j < it2->second.size() ) {
      if( it1->second[i] < it2->second[j] ) {
        i++; 
      } else if( it1->second[i] > it2->second[j] ) {
        j++; 
      } else {
        i++; j++; _inter++;
      }
    }
    _union = it1->second.size() + it2->second.size() - _inter;

    if ( (double) _inter / _union > THRESH )
      cout << it1->first << " might appears frequently with " << it2->first << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: In what sense is this "parallel"?

Comment: Also, this code has no observable side effects (the inner loop only affects variables within the scope of the loop).  What is the output here?

Comment: You have simplified this code to the point where it doesn't actually achieve anything.  What are you actually trying to do with your data?  It looks like you're trying to count the number of duplicate values across all your mapped arrays.  Is that correct?

Comment: It appears that your "parallel comparison" is equivalent to `_inter = std::set_intersection(it1->second, it2->second).size()`. Not sure that'll be faster, but it certainly seems like it's worth a test (note that I'm using shorthand -- each `itN->second` will really need to be a `.begin()`, `.end()` pair).

Comment: Hi @OliCharlesworth, the key represents the "word", to be simplified, I replace it with number; the second part is the document ID that has the word inside the document. I try to find the words pairs that has most documents overlap. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @paddy, please see last comment, thank you :)

Comment: Hi @jerryCoffin, thank you for that. Let me try :)

Comment: Based on your description above, instead of storing a list of the documents in which a word occurs, perhaps it would make sense to create a bit-vector with a bit for each document, that you set to 1 to mean the document contains that word, or 0 to mean it doesn't. Then finding the overlap means a bitwise `and` of the vectors followed by counting the `1` bits.

Comment: @Jerry: I imagine the bitmap would be quite sparse, and actually take more memory and time.

Comment: Hi @JerryCoffin, I'm very new to your idea. I haven't use bitwise operator before. For me, probably I will use bool value to mark it. Need a hand for how to define a bit-vector in c/c++

Comment: C++ has a `std::bit_vector` that *might* work for you.

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt, I have same concern with you. That why there exists inverted indexing in Information Retrieval System. But, anyway, I can try Jerry's advise and see how it going, thank you :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I will try your idea and will let you how it works. If there is any new brainstorm, please feel free let me know :) thanks

Comment: @BenVoigt, if you have some good idea, please let me know PLEASE !

Comment: None except the obvious: use threads for parallel execution, even use a cluster

Comment: @AlexLee Using a bit vector seems like a good idea. How many documents do you have in total? And, are the word IDs sequential (like 0, 1, etc) or are random (like a hash value, for example)?

Comment: @yzt I have around 130k document, and the word ID is sequential as I sorted the words alphabetically.

Comment: @BenVoigt any cluster algorithm to use from your knowledge?

Comment: Well there's a thought.  Documents that are strongly correlated with each other will have similar scores when compared to other documents.

Comment: @BenVoigt, you are right. Here, my experiment is not that way, but it is possible by clustering. I try to find word's correlation by checking the overlap of document, which is comparatively weak but worthy to try :)

Comment: Hi @JerryCoffin, the bit_vector is not available in newest STL because bit_vector is a separate class, instead of a template specialization of vector<bool>, is that this would require partial specialization of templates    cite: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bit_vector.html. Except vector<bool>, is there any alternative similar 'bit_vector'?

Comment: @AlexLee: Oops -- yeah (problem of old age). Alternatives include vector<bool>, std::bitset, and Boost [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Comment: @JerryCoffin wonderful, thumbs up!!!

Comment: @AlexLee You probably can use the code I've posted below (in my answer) instead of a complete bit vector implementation. It only provides the operations you need (as far as I know) and the "intersect" operation should be faster here because you only need the cardinality of the intersection, and not the actual common elements (at least you don't need the elements at first.)

Comment: Hi @JerryCoffin the bit_vector doesn't work. Thank you for your advise any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is not a complete answer. It only solves part of your problem; the part about bit manipulation.)

Here's a class you might be able to use to calculate the number of intersections between two sets (the cardinality of the intersection) rather quickly.

It uses a bit vector to store the sets, which means the universe of the possible set members must be small.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

class BitVector
{
    // IMPORTANT: U must be unsigned
    // IMPORTANT: use unsigned long long in 64-bit builds.
    typedef unsigned long U;
    static const unsigned UBits = 8 * sizeof(U);

public:
    BitVector (unsigned size)
        : m_bits ((size + UBits - 1) / UBits, 0)
        , m_size (size)
    {
    }

    void set (unsigned bit)
    {
        assert (bit < m_size);
        m_bits[bit / UBits] |= (U)1 << (bit % UBits);
    }

    void clear (unsigned bit)
    {
        assert (bit < m_size);
        m_bits[bit / UBits] &= ~((U)1 << (bit % UBits));
    }

    unsigned countIntersect (BitVector const & that) const
    {
        assert (m_size == that.m_size);

        unsigned ret = 0;
        for (std::vector<U>::const_iterator i = m_bits.cbegin(),
             j = that.m_bits.cbegin(), e = m_bits.cend(), f = that.m_bits.cend();
             i != e && j != f; ++i, ++j)
        {
            U x = *i & *j;

            // Count the number of 1 bits in x and add it to ret
            // There are much better ways than this,
            // e.g. using the POPCNT instruction or intrinsic
            while (x != 0)
            {
                ret += x & 1;
                x >>= 1;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    unsigned countUnion (BitVector const & that) const
    {
        assert (m_size == that.m_size);

        unsigned ret = 0;
        for (std::vector<U>::const_iterator i = m_bits.cbegin(),
             j = that.m_bits.cbegin(), e = m_bits.cend(), f = that.m_bits.cend();
             i != e && j != f; ++i, ++j)
        {
            U x = *i | *j;

            while (x != 0)
            {
                ret += x & 1;
                x >>= 1;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

private:
    std::vector<U> m_bits;
    unsigned m_size;
};
```

And here's a very small test program to see how you can use the above class. It makes two sets (each with 100K maximum elements), adds some items to them (using the `set()` member function) and then calculate their intersection 1 billion times. It runs in under two seconds on my machine.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    unsigned const SetSize = 100000;
    BitVector a (SetSize), b (SetSize);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < SetSize; i += 2) a.set (i);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < SetSize; i += 3) b.set (i);
    
    unsigned x = a.countIntersect (b);
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to compile this with optimizations enabled! Otherwise it performs very badly.

### POPCNT

Modern processors have an instruction to count the number of set bits in a word, called POPCNT. This is quite a lot faster than doing the naive thing written above (as a side note, there are faster ways to do it in software as well, but I didn't want to pollute the code.)

Anyways, the way to use POPCNT in C/C++ code is to use a compiler *intrinsic* or *built-in*. In MSVC, you can use `__popcount()` intrinsic that works on 32-bit integers. In GCC, you can use `__builtin_popcountl()` for 32-bit integers and `__builtin_popcountll()` for 64 bits. Be warned that these functions may not be available due to your compiler version, target architecture and/or compile switches.

Comment: I can't complete my answer (to give you a full explanation of what you can do) right now, but if you have any comments/questions, I'll be back in a few hours.

Comment: Hi @yzt, if i want to know the union of the two sequence? E.g {1,2,3} and {2,3,4} their union is 4 and intersection is 2

Comment: @AlexLee: It's simple and equally fast. I'll edit my answer to add the union. You just do a bitwise-OR, instead of a bitwise-AND. Also, if you want to count the differences between two sets, i.e. (a-b)U(b-a), you can use XOR.

Comment: Hi @yzt, I partly understand your code. The problem is that when I try to compile two files, compiler told me: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of "i" with no type (for i e f j iterators); invalid type argument of 'unary *' for (U x = *i | *j ;)  My system is ubuntu 9.10 2.6.32-33-generic and g++ 4.4.3

Comment: I used "g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -o main" to compile file. Did i miss sth or optimizations?

Comment: Oh! I'm using `auto` from C++11, and I don't know whether GCC 4.4 supports it or not. Will edit the code to use only C++03 features.

Comment: Hi @yzt, I tried it, but cannot imagine you finish it in two seconds. How did you optimize the compile? My machine runs for a very long time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30989/discussion-between-alex-lee-and-yzt)

Comment: hi @yzt, in your test code, there are only two objects a and b. If I have 2 million objects rather than two, how will I handle them? because it really suck memory. I only have 24GB Ram.

Comment: @AlexLee: There are no magic bullets here! With a dataset that large, you can't hold it all in memory. You must keep it on disk and load part of it (a few hundred or thousand items at a time) into memory and work on them, then load the next part, then the next part, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to try [PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx). Or some of its analogues. I don't really understand what your code suppose to do, as it doesn't seem to have any output. But side effects free code can be effectively parallelized with tools like Parallel Patterns Library.

Comment: Hi @akalenuk, I updated my code. Please also take a look at the fifth commend of under original question if you are interested in. Thank you for your answers. I'm trying the code yzt supple to me.